# How to add Recently opened files item to xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin right pane?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce4

In xfce4-whiskermenu the right pane has an item **Recently Used**, it is for apps/programs. I'd to know if is possible to add an item to show **Recently Opened Files** to the right pane of xfce4-whiskermenu. 
OS: Xubuntu 16.04.6

thanks, vladi

Answer (score 0):

Not with Whisker. The panel plugin you're looking for is **Places** (xfce4-places-plugin).